Weird fan or exhaust fan like noise from wall
We just had our power go on and off last few days just for a minute or two but came back.
Now suddenly yesterday started having some weird issue and dnt knw what to do .. in my living room  .. where I have mounted my TV suddenly there is some fan like noise.. there is no fan or exhaust fan close by and all electric outlets I have unplugged ... but still that fan kindaa noise ... once I switch off the breaker for family room from the main box the noise stops .. and then when I turn it back on it starts.. nt even sure whats happening but sounds electric. I have unplugged my tv from the outlet and there is nothing connected and I even tried turning all breakers off and on but still sound persists when I turn on the family/living room breaker. When I turn it off the sound stops. Attaching the pic

Are any of those switches dimmers?  Dimmers can buzz.

Switches/outlets/wires in the walls should not make noise.  Finding where the noise is coming from will help, but having the breaker on to locate it, might be dangerous(fire).  You do need to keep the breaker off, except for a few minutes at a time trying to locate the noise.  One decent bet would be outlets with the push in wire connections instead of screws.  Power going off and on might have loosen one or more connections.

Thank you @crip659 appreciate your guidance, I was able to get this fixed with the help of a professional electrician. Turned out to be the transformer behind the Chime (door bell) which was damaged and causing that humming/fan like noise. The transformed/Chime was on the same wall and  I didnt even think it was the one causing but the electrician helped look and resolve it. I had to replace the Chime and transformed and that fixed the issue.

I was able to get this issue of (humming/vibration/fan like noise from wall) fixed with the help of a professional electrician. Turned out to be the transformer behind the Chime (door bell) which was damaged and causing that humming/fan like noise from the wall. The transformer/Chime was on the same wall and I didn't even think it was the one causing but the electrician helped look and resolve it. I had to replace the Chime and transformer and that fixed the issue.
